# How to use the same style for the unnumbered chapters as the numbered chapters?

Tags: chapters, styles

I'm using this style for the numbered chapters in my report but it doesn't use the same style for the unnumbered. How do I fix that?

```
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \color{martec} \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@ }
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{0\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill\color{martec1}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule height 0.3ex
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par 
        \vspace*{5\p@}%
        \hrule height 0.1ex
    \vskip 30\p@
   % \vskip 100\p@
  }}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this forum, so I don't know what a Minimal Working Example is.

Comment: See [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many packages to help you with the design of chapter styles.

Try for example the package `fncychap`.

(Unless of course you want to sharpen your TeX programming skills)

Meanwhile try this code.

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \color{red} \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@ }

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    %\vspace*{50\p@}%
    \vspace*{0\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill\color{green}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule height 0.3ex
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par 
        \vspace*{5\p@}%
        \hrule height 0.1ex
        \vskip 30\p@
        % \vskip 100\p@
}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
        \vspace*{0\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font  
         \thickhrulefill\color{green}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule height 0.3ex
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par 
        \vspace*{5\p@}%
        \hrule height 0.1ex
        \vskip 30\p@
    }}

\makeatother

\begin{document}    
    
\chapter*{No numbered}

\chapter{With number}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Just what I needed! :)